# My $scope.product still changing even I already passed its value to another variable which is $scope.editOrDeleteProduct

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

First I use my $scope.product in my table

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products ng-click="productClicked(product)">

        <td>{{product.prod_name}}</td>
        <td>{{product.company}}</td>

</tr>
```

Then my productClicked in my controller is something like this

```
$scope.productClicked = function (product) {
  $scope.editOrDeleteProduct = product;
}
```

I am passing the value to another editOrDeleteProduct. I am using editOrDeleteProduct in my form.

```
     <input type="text" class="form-control empty" id="inputProductname" placeholder="Enter product name." ng-model="editOrDeleteProduct.prod_name" disabled>
     <input type="text" class="form-control empty" id="inputBrand" placeholder="Enter the company." ng-model="editOrDeleteProduct.company" disabled>
```

Then when I change something in the form the data in the table which is passed in the editOrDeleteProduct also change. I just wanna know what is going on there and how can change something in the form without changing any data in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use deep copy use  `angular.copy(product);`

```
  $scope.editOrDeleteProduct = angular.copy(product);
```